# Can I make an instance of inner static class?

Tags: android, nested-class

If I use the **code 1**
`Utility.DetailsInfo myInfo=new Utility.DetailsInfo()` causes an error, why?
`No enclosing instance of type Utility is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Utility`
**(e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Utility).**

So I have to use the **Code 2**
Can I make an instance of inner static class?
 Thanks!

**Code 1**

```
public class Utility {

    class DetailsInfo {
        String title;
        String path;
        String size;
        Bitmap thumbnails;
    }

    public static void GetPhotoDetailsByID(Context mycontext,String id,DetailsInfo myInfo ){
             Cursor cur = mycontext.getContentResolver().query(
                     MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                     null,
                     MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+"=?", 
                     new String[]{id},
                     "" );
             if (cur.moveToFirst()){
                 myInfo.title= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
                 myInfo.path = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                 myInfo.size=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE));

                 myInfo.thumbnails = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                                   mycontext.getContentResolver(), 
                                   Integer.parseInt(id),
                                   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, 
                                   null);

             }
             cur.close();
        }       
}
```

**Code 2**

```
public class Utility {    
    public static class DetailsInfo {
        String title;
        String path;
        String size;
        Bitmap thumbnails;
    }

    public static void GetPhotoDetailsByID(Context mycontext,String id,DetailsInfo myInfo ){
             Cursor cur = mycontext.getContentResolver().query(
                     MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                     null,
                     MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+"=?", 
                     new String[]{id},
                     "" );
             if (cur.moveToFirst()){
                 myInfo.title= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
                 myInfo.path = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                 myInfo.size=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE));

                 myInfo.thumbnails = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                                   mycontext.getContentResolver(), 
                                   Integer.parseInt(id),
                                   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, 
                                   null);

             }
             cur.close();
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you..

This line will cause error because you have to call the inner class with the object of its parent class..

```
Utility.DetailsInfo myInfo=new Utility.DetailsInfo();
```

Child class can be referred with its parent class object only if it is not static..

**Like:**

```
Utility utility = new Utility();
Utility.DetailsInfo myInfo= new utility.DetailsInfo();
```

And yes you can make instance of **inner class static** Directly as it is declared static..

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the first instance of the code is that your inner class is not static.  This means that in order to have a new instantiate an instance of Utility.DetailsInfo you need to do the following:

```
Utility foo = new Utility();
Utility.DetailsInfo bar = foo.new DetailsInfo();
```

In the second case, `Utility.DetailsInfo` is static, so you can directly instantiate a version of `Utility.DetailsInfo` without instantiating a class of `Utility`.  For more reading and info about nested classes [check the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 0):

In code 1, Since `Utility.DetailsInfo` is not static you can't use itwithout instantiating. So first instantiate an object of `Utility`, then try to access it's inner class `DetailsInfo`.

```
Utility utility = new Utility();
Utility.DetailsInfo myInfo= utility.new DetailsInfo();
```

However in code 2, since `DetailsInfo` is defined as static class you can instantiate it directly.

```
Utility.DetailsInfo myInfo = new Utility.DetailsInfo();
```

Ideally it is logical to embed a class in another class only if it is useful only to outer class. In such cases nesting "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined or else try to avoid them.